# ASP.NET Hierarchical menu editor

Tags: asp.net, menu, hierarchy

I have read many references and found various options for displaying a menu using jquery/json, but I need an editor solution that will show my hierarchical menu as some editable form allowing maybe drag/drop to re-order, but I also need to be able to update the Menu table in the database.

The menu table is a parent/child table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Menu](
    [MenuID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Enabled] [bit] NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
    [PageID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Menu] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MenuID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

e.g.

```
MenuID  DateCreated Title   Enabled ParentID    PageID
1   2018-03-01 08:26:10.217 Who We Are  1   0   0
2   2018-03-01 08:26:14.520 What We Do  1   0   0
3   2018-03-01 08:26:18.177 Help Us 1   0   0
4   2018-03-01 08:26:22.713 Work With Us    1   0   0
5   2018-03-01 08:26:28.897 Buy With Us 1   0   0
6   2018-03-01 08:26:31.807 News    1   0   72
7   2018-03-01 08:57:23.270 About   1   1   2
8   2018-03-01 08:57:29.457 Our services    1   1   4
9   2018-03-01 08:57:33.913 History 1   1   5
10  2018-03-01 08:57:37.723 Staff   1   1   0
11  2018-03-01 08:57:46.017 Who pays    1   1   9
12  2018-03-01 08:57:51.237 Directors   1   1   0
13  2018-03-01 08:58:25.323 Our  Team   1   10  6
14  2018-03-01 08:58:30.943 Backers 1   10  7
15  2018-03-01 08:58:41.557 Support 1   10  8
16  2018-03-01 08:59:11.150 How We're Checked   1   12  10
17  2018-03-01 08:59:19.450 Submit Feedback 1   12  11
18  2018-03-01 08:59:25.523 Buy with Confidence 1   12  12
```

I did find for example this, but it means I need to convert to JSON my Menu table and then do the reverse in order to update to the Menu database table.

Is there something asp.net oriented already available?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an ASP_Panel and load all menus from code behind? Doing so,you could use the drag and drop feature described in : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp, because everytime the js function is called, you could use an asp:hiddenfield where you append its content by the controls id. When the user is done making changes, read the hiddenfield value. Now you know the changed positions and how to update the table.

Best Regards,

Maheshvara